# Why the E- in Etruscan?

Tags: latin

The Etruscans had several names in antiquity: the Greeks called them Tyrsenoi or Tyrrhenoi, the Roman Tusci or Etrusci (and their country Etruria). All these names seem to be related, ultimately coming from a root Turs- (or maybe Trus-). (The Etruscans themselves seem to have used a completely different name, Rasenna or Rasna.)

Thus Turs- plus the Greek ethnonymic suffix -en- gives Tyrsenoi (or Tyrrhenoi with the regular change -rs- > -ss-). In Latin, Turs-ci would give Tusci. With metathesis, Turs- becomes Trus-, and this seems to underlie E-trus-ci and E-trur-ia (from E-trus-ia with regular rhotacism). But why the E- in these last two forms?

Adding prothetic e- before a consonant cluster is, of course, something that many languages do, but Latin doesn't. Latin has no problem with words beginning tr-, so there's no reason to add an initial e-. The only hypothesis I can think of is that the Romans got this name through some other, unknown language which didn't allow initial consonant clusters, and the e- is due to that language. This is probably an unanswerable question, but has anyone speculated about this initial e-?

Comment: Doesn't it come from Etruscan itself, this prothetic e? Hix 2008 argues there was a prefix e- in Etruscan.

Comment: @AlexB. Interesting. I can't find the article - what's the function of this initial e-?

Comment: Sorry, of course it should be Helmut Rix (Rix 2004, reprinted  2008: 149) - mea culpa.

Comment: Also Rix 2004 wasn't the first one who came up with this idea.  I haven't properly researched this problem, but I know that Tronskii 1953 offered the same explanation.

Comment: @AlexB. Thanks! Looks like Rix actually mentions the word Etruscan specifically as an example of this prefix e-, but he doesn't say what the prefix means. Still, that's probably a partial solution to the problem, at least.